# Which object/control is used to scroll horizontally in an apple watch app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-watch

I am creating an apple watch app and want to scroll horizontally like on iPhone using uiscrollview.

Which object/control is used to scroll horizontally in an apple watch app?

Comment: The its done on other iOS devices is with a scroll view who's content width is wider than its bounds width.

Answer (score 7):

There is no horizontal scrolling on the Apple Watch, the closest you can get is by using multiple WKInterfaceControllers arranged as pages.  The only scrolling control provided is the WKInterfaceTable control, which is vertical only.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the closest you can get to horizontal scrolling is arranging your views with a page-based layout. Create a main Interface Controller scene on your WatchOS Storyboard, and right-click drag it to the next Interface Controller, marking the Relationship Segue as "next page". This will create a page-based layout between the views. To make a third "page", drag the second Interface Controller to a third one as a "next page" segue again, and so on.

For further reference and reading, see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/InterfaceStyles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH12-SW1

Comment: @JayMayu, never tried. It is possible that the controller behaves like a TabBar in the sense of adding controllers to it or the like, but even if it does, I'm not sure it would be wise. Do you have a reason you need to do it programatically rather than via Interface Builder?